# Codeigniter - Download a upload file in the directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, file-upload, download

I'm using the latest Codeigniter version, and I write a program about basic file uploading and download helper in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/download_helper.html.

I want to create a system that will upload a multiple files to the directory and save the file name to the database and the name of the uploader, and will have function to have download links to download every file of that specific user. **If possible** the system can email the encrypted link to the users to download the file. And can only download for specific time..

I don't know the logic in dynamic files to download. Can someone teach how to do this or what logic can solve this problem. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

For multiple files you have some alternatives, you can create each field as a user press a button or use the `multiple` propriety to `<input>` tag.

To manage this multiple uploads you must create your own upload library reading each `$_FILES['nameoffield']` in a `foreach` loop for example although there are alternatives ready to be used like: https://github.com/nicdev/CodeIgniter-Multiple-File-Upload

On your database, you could have two fields that stores the original file name and path, and the encrypted one. Probably associated to a random unique number or timestamp.

To email encrypted link, and by encrypted I think you are saying a disguised link to the file, not using original name, you simple select the field which store the encrypted name to a controller, like download and keep a variable to receive a value as parameter. This value you must check on database if it really exists and then redirect to the file. By doing that you should have your file being downloaded.

Comment: how about to have different random link, every time a user download the file through website or email encrypted link? I don't know how to do that.. :(

Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: can you teach me how to use function of do_multi_upload() in https://github.com/nicdev/CodeIgniter-Multiple-File-Upload

--this is my code in controller. how can I apply that here?

    `function file_upload(){
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('gallery/gallery', $error);
        }
        else{
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('gallery/upload_success', $data);
        }`